# C# - Properties versus accessor methods?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

From what I can tell, properties are used to provide accessor method-esque functionality; however, they do so at the cost of normal method inheritance behavior. Are there any advantages to using properties versus conventional setter/getter methods? What are the pros/cons of properties and accessor methods?

Comment: Your first example compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: You are still inheriting those members, it's just that when in the derived class you specify that you want to query the `Datum` property you need to specify that you want to access the base classes implementation of Datum (`base.Datum = 2`) - though I'm sure it should work regardless (you definitely need to use the superclass accessor when you override Datum and still want to query the base implementation)

Comment: Hmm, for some reason, under one project, I'm getting an error, but putting that in a new project runs fine. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confused. In your examples, the above methods should be accessible. For example, given this set of types, the following should work:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual int Datum { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override int Datum
    {
        get { return 12; }
        // set method remains as normal, with just the get overriden
    }

    public void SetDatumMethod(int newValue)
    {
        Datum = newValue; // Datum as a property is still accessible
    }
}
```

The derived class still inherits the property. Properties really are just syntactic sugar in C# (mostly), as the compiler is generating `set_Datum(int x)` and `get_Datum()` methods behind the scenes for you. The property get/set methods can still be overridden individually as shown above.

The advantage of using properties is that they have additional semantic meaning; they "contain" or "represent" data in some fashion, not a method for generating the data.

Comment: Gotcha. Note, you're right about my example, I removed it as it is invalid. Also, what about "hiding" of properties (I don't exactly understand it, but I don't think you can hide an accessor method like you can a property)? I remember having other difficulties when trying to treat properties as accessor methods, although I can't remember any off hand. So far, your answer has been helpful, but I would appreciate more information if more exists.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to verify that your answer was a thorough comparison of the two, rather than a generalization.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio debugger executes the getter method when watching an object.  That is, property accessors are executed at unpredictable times and should thus not cause any discernable side-effects.  Abusing properties can lead to difficult bugsto resolve .

Another reason to use a method is that order retrieval is likely to be parameterized.

A good practice is for property access to be computationally cheap; client code should not be forced to place the property value into a local variable - it's premature optimization.

Comment: How do you mean "abusing properties"? Can you be more specific about what constitutes abuse and the potential resultant bugs? Furthermore, what is "order retrieval", and can you be more specific as to why "parameterized order retrieval" is better than whatever sort of "order retrieval" properties use? Finally, I don't understand what you mean when you suggest making property access "computationally cheap". And under what circumstances would client code be forced to place the property value into a local variable? Can you provide examples for these scenarios?